# Navigator.popUntil flutter show black screen

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

I have two different flows in my project.

1. Main Page -> PageA -> Page B -> Page C -> Page A

From Page C to Page A, I use this code , which works fine.

```
   Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(AssetMenu.ROUTE));
```

2. When receive push notification, user tap on the push notification, I want it straight away navigate like this

Main Page -> Page B -> Page C -> then back to Page A when button in Page C is clicked.

But when button in Page C is clicked, it shows black screen.

How should I handle this?

Comment: Maybe read this Medium post to get a better understanding of navigator: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31 and then this one: https://ptyagicodecamp.github.io/navigation-and-routing-in-flutter-app.html both very good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your second use case `Page A` is missing. When you invoke `Navigator.popUntil()` the navigator goes up the stack of routes and pops them until it find the specified one. If the specified route is not on the stack, it will remove routes until the stack is empty. That is why you get the black screen.

If you want to turn `Main Page -> Page B -> Page C` into `Main Page -> Page A` you have to invoke [`Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html) where the new route is `Page A` and the predicate matches the `Main Page`. Alternatively use [`Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html).

Comment: If I use `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()`, when I press back button in Page A, will it back to main page?

Comment: And what is the condition to check is it tapped on notification or not?

Comment: You could use the method for both use cases. First, the navigator pushes `Page A`. Then, it removes all routes before `Page A`. `Page C` is removed first, then `Page B`. If `Page A` was part of the initial route stack, it will be removed at third. The navigator then comes to `Main Page`. It sees that this is the route where it is supposed to stop removing routes. The navigator now has a route stack of `Main Page -> Page A`.

Comment: So, yes if you invoke `Navigator.pop()` then, it will remove `Page A` and navigate to `Main Page`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get you. Why page c will be removed first?

Comment: Because it's the last one that was added to the route stack. The navigator iterates over the stack (it could also be a list or array) beginning at the end. Do you know what a stack is?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try this

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AssetMenu(),), (route) => route.isFirst);
```

Comment: What if I want to use Router?

Comment: What do you mean by  `Router` ? `ModalRoute.withName(AssetMenu.ROUTE)` ?

Comment: Ya. And how did I know user is tapped on notification or not in order to perform different navigator method?

Comment: You wrote this `then back to Page A when button in Page C is clicked`. Navigation is done intentionally. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using name routes, it's more easy even if you're app gets bigger with more pages. I prefer to let widgets outside main.dart and inside dart just use logic and routes, and after Create those 3 pages that you need A,B,C and set in you're main dart code that you're first page(home page) has to be page A.

Go on you're pages and just under Statefull{ or Stateless { type the route name:

```
static const routeName = '/pageA';
static const routeName = '/pageB';
static const routeName = '/pageC';
```

Define in your main.dart the routes:

```
home: WidgetFromPageA(),
      routes: {
        WidgetFromPageB.routeName: (ctx) => WidgetFromPageB(),
        WidgetFromPageC.routeName: (ctx) => WidgetFromPageC(),
        },
```

From any page you can call this action:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(WidgetFromPageA.routeName);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(WidgetFromPageB.routeName);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(WidgetFromPageC.routeName);
```

In this way you can go to page B and on the new page in the app bar you got the return button.
For example, when you are in the second page, use the pushReplacement() method and open the third page, when you hit the back button you will go to the first page and skip the second page.

To make it more clear you can navigate to the forth page like this:

`[ 1 --push()--> 2 --pushReplacement()--> 3 --pushReplacement()--> 4]` and when you hit the back button you will get to the first page.

Answer (score 1):

Do this if you want to go to the main page when you are **not** using named Routes

```dart
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) {
   if (route.settings.name != "/") return false;
   return true;
});
```

Comment: this can be simplified to `return route.settings.name == "/"`